Compute the genus of a double cover of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ branched at 12 points
I am studying Riemann Surfaces and the lecturer gave the following as an exercise:

Compute the genus of a double cover of of $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ branched at 12 points

I would appreciate some advice in case my attempt is wrong or missing some consideration. Here are the definitions I'm working with:

Consider a non-constant holomorphic map $f: X \to Y$
between Riemann surfaces. For any point $x \in X$, the local form of holomorphic functions guarantees that there exists local coordinate $(z, w)$ centred at $(x, f(x))$ such that
the function $f$ has the form
$$z \mapsto z^k$$ for some positive integer $k$. This means that there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $f(x)$, $U',V' \subset \mathbb{C}$ and homeomorphisms $\varphi: U \to U'$, $\psi: V \to V'$ such that
$$(\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1})(z)=z^k$$ With the notation above, define the multiplicity of $f$ at the point $x \in X$ to be
$$\mu_x(f)=k$$
A function with $\mu_x(f)=1$ is called unramified at $x \in X$, and ramified if $\mu_x(f) \geq 2$. Such a point is called a ramification point
The ramification locus is defined as
$$\mathrm{Ram}(f)=\{x \in X: x \ \text{ramification point}\}$$
If $x \in \mathrm{Ram}(f)$ is a ramification point, then $f(x) \in Y$ is called a branch point
Consider any $f: X \to Y$ holomorphic between compact Riemann Surfaces. Then the degree $d$
$$d=\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mu_x(f)$$
of $f$ is independent of $y$, that is a constant.

My attempt: We are given $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ with 12 branch points on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ and degree $d=2$. By Riemann Hurwitz Formula we get
$$2g_X-2=2 \cdot (2g_{\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})}-2)+\sum_{x \in \mathrm{Ram(f)}}(\mu_x(f)-1)$$
$$2g_X-2=-4+\sum_{x \in \mathrm{Ram(f)}}(\mu_x(f)-1)$$
$$2g_X+2=\sum_{x \in \mathrm{Ram(f)}}\mu_x(f)-|\mathrm{Ram}(f)|$$
Now my claim is that we have 12 ramification points and each has multiplicity 2. For the degree $d$ of a holomorphic map it holds
$$d=\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mu_x(f)$$ for arbitrary $y \in Y=\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$. Then since multiplicities are positive integers, we either have
$$2=d=\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mu_x(f)=1+1$$ or
$$2=d=\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mu_x(f)=2+0$$
If we choose y to be a branch point, then $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ is by definition a ramification point meaning its multiplicity is at least 2. This means each branch point has exactly one preimage (is this trivial?). Thus, the sum
$$2=d=\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}\mu_x(f)=2+0$$ is actually just the single multiplicity $\mu_x(f)=2$. Any branch point of the 12 in total has exactly one ramification point corresponding to it. Thus we get
$$2g_X+2=\sum_{x \in \mathrm{Ram(f)}}\mu_x(f)-|\mathrm{Ram}(f)|$$
$$2g_X+2=24-12$$
$$2g_X+2=12$$
which implies $g_X=5$
